# Unable to pass data from one component to another in next js 14

Tags: next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am passing data from one component to another using query but I am getting data undefined or
`{ params: {}, searchParams: {} }`
but on ProductData component I am getting data correctly pls let me know what I am doing wrong in below code and I also want to know how to pass data from child to parent in next js
`ProductData.tsx`

```
import apiData from "@/app/products/api-data/page";
import Link from "next/link";
import { ApiData } from "./apiCall";

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function ProductData() {
  const apiResult = await ApiData();

    return(
        <div>
        {
            apiResult &&  apiResult.data?.products.map((item:any, id:number) => {
                  return(
                      <div key={id}>
                      <h4>Name: {item?.title}  Price: {item?.price} </h4>
                  </div>
                  )
              })
          }

<Link
     href={{ pathname: '/about', query: { data: JSON.stringify(apiResult.data) } }}
 as='/about'
    >
      About Us
    </Link>
{/* <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        router.push({
          pathname: '/about',
          query: { products :JSON.stringify(data) },
        })
      }}
    >
      About Us
    </button> */}
          </div>
    )
}
```

`ApiCall.tsx`

```
"use server"
export const ApiData = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
    const data = await response.json();
return{
    data
}  
}
```

and
 `about.tsx`

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'About page',
}
export default function About(searchParams:any) {

  console.log(searchParams)
  // const data = products?.searchParams?.products;
  

  return(
<div>
<h1>About</h1>
{/* {
    data && data.map((item:any, id:number) => {
        console.log(item,"itemitemitemitemitemitem")
        return(
          <div key={id}>{item?.brand}</div>
        )
      })
    } */}
    
</div>
   
  )
}
```

I want to pass data from ProductData component to about page.tsx but unable to do so pls help

Answer (score 1):

First off. I don't think it's a good idea to pass data from one component to another using params. Because there a risk that user will visit about page without params. What's stopping you from fetching the data In about page component?

```
const AboutPage = async () => {
    const apiResult = await ApiData();
  return (
    <div>
    <AboutPageContent apiData={apiResult} childDataToParent={(value) => {
    // Hello
     console.log(value);
    }} />
   </div>
  )
}
export default AboutPage
```

```
"use client"

interface IAboutPageContent {
  apiResults: apiInterface
  childDataToParent: (data: string) => void;
 }
 const AboutPageContent = ({ apiResults, childDataToParent }: IAboutPageContent) => {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => {
   // passing data from child to parent
    childDataToParent("hello")
    }}>AboutPageContent</div>
  )
}
export default AboutPageContent
```

Comment: I was learning about passing data through props on navigation suppose the component dosent have any relation and also I want to use meta data on AboutPage so it will be a server component and how to pass data like there are some cases where we have to pass id from api or a data of array of object in a button how to pass it when there is no relation only we are navigating

Comment: If you want to pass data like that you should look into state management like redux-toolkit. Next has an example on how to implement. In my example aboutPage is server component.  According to next you should fetch data inside server component. You can also use fetch or react cache functions explained in the documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns